# C# use a string value as the name of an integer

Tags: c#

In the below example is it possible to use the kvp.value to point a global variable (num1, num2, num3)?

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<KeyValuePair<TextBox, string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<TextBox, string>>(); 
   myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<TextBox, string>(textBox1, "num1"));
   myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<TextBox, string>(textBox2, "num2"));
   myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<TextBox, string>(textBox3, "num3"));

          foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBox, string> kvp in myList)
          {
              TextBox tb= kvp.Key;
              try
              {
                  num1 = int.Parse(tb.Text);
                  //instead of using the hardcoded variable name num1 i want to use kvp.value
                  //kvp.value = int.Parse(tb.Text);
              }
              catch
              {
                  //blah blah
              }

          }

}
```

I deleted my previous post as it was very unclear, hopefully this is a bit better.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection-field i think it's what you want

Comment: Do you need to use the variable num1, num2, num3 anywhere else in the code?

Comment: yes they are used else where

Comment: I would suggest a dictionary<string, int> would be more performant and provide what you want here.

Comment: You should consider using 'enum' to have a set of named integers. Best regards,

Comment: What is the intended usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you can change your global variables (from int) to reference type, by introducing a wrapper class:

```
class Number<T>
{
    public Number(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Your code will be:

```
Number<int> num1 = new Number<int>(0);
Number<int> num2 = new Number<int>(0);
Number<int> num3 = new Number<int>(0);



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<TextBox, Number<int>>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<TextBox, Number<int>>>();
    myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<TextBox, Number<int>>(textBox1, num1));
    myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<TextBox, Number<int>>(textBox2, num2));
    myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<TextBox, Number<int>>(textBox3, num3));

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBox, Number<int>> kvp in myList)
    {
        TextBox tb = kvp.Key;
        try
        {
            kvp.Value.Value = int.Parse(tb.Text);
            //instead of using the hardcoded variable name num1 i want to use kvp.value
            //kvp.value = int.Parse(tb.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            //blah blah
        }

    }

}
```